# Passing multiple parameters in $stateParams

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In the ui-router tutorial https://plnkr.co/edit/jbZgIg?p=info, they are passing a single parameter **personId** to the state.

```
ui-sref="people.person({ personId: person.id })"
```

and the state is:

```
{ 
  name: 'people.person', 
  url: '/{personId}', 
  component: 'person',
  resolve: {
    person: function(people, $stateParams) {
      return people.find(function(person) { 
        return person.id === $stateParams.personId;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I am working on an example in which I want to pass 2 parameters (1 visible using the url, and the second hidden which will be the id that the user can't see in the url). Something similar to:

```
ui-sref="people.person({ personId: person.id, personUri : person.uri })"
```

and I want the state to become something like this (but it didn't work!):

```
{ 
  name: 'people.person', 
  url: '/{personUri}',
  component: 'person',
  resolve: {
    person: function(people, $stateParams) {
      return people.find(function(person) { 
        return person.id === $stateParams.personId;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

As the state shows, I want to use the **personUri** in the url, and I want the **personId** to be passed to the **people** service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use params

```
.state('other', {
    url: '/:personUri',
    params: { 
        personUri:"",

        // this param is not part of url
        // it could be passed with $state.go or ui-sref 
        personId: "",
      }
...
```

Comment: I want to receive the values of personUri and personId from the resolve. You set their params to "" ??? I want the values not "" !!!!!

Comment: "" is a default value. when you use ui-sref="people.person({ personId: person.id, personUri : person.uri })", you'll get values. you can set it to null if you don't wan't use default value.

Comment: Understood :) and tested :) and working ;) thanks dear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing your object in url parameters you can simply call your controller's function by passing in your object and then do whatever you want to do with that object in your controller itself and then call your service inside it.

Example:

```
$scope.func = function info(person){
    console.log(person);
    PeopleService.xyz(person).then(function(response){
        console.log('Service called')
    })
  }
```

In html call it like this :

```
<button ng-click="func(person)"> Click me</button>
```

Comment: But the implication is that the parameters will be needed by the next state. So, calling the next state's controller isn't going to be much use. Also, even assuming that you did want to use it in this state, there may be async/await issues that he may not want (thus putting them in the ui-router's state resolve would be beneficial, if using in that state).